Django return "You are not allowed to perform this action." when creating a new entry
I have an application which i want to run scripts. Those scripts are stored in a database. This is how i do all of this using Django 5.0.1 :
First of all, this is my settings file :
#...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Django apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # My apps
    'personal',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

#...

This is my urls file :
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #...
]

This is my models file :
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.conf import settings

from os.path import join

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Type(models.Model):
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    complete_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.complete_name

class Version(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)

    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['product', 'version'], name='unique_product_version'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product} {self.version}"
        
class TypeTestRelation(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, null=False, blank=False, related_name='attributed_tests', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['type', 'test']

class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=join(join(settings.BASE_DIR, "static"), "scripts"), null=True, blank=False)  # Add the file field
    test_result = models.FileField(upload_to=join(join(settings.BASE_DIR, "static"), "test_results"), null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    versions = models.ManyToManyField(Version, through='TestVersionRelation')
    types = models.ManyToManyField(Type, through='TypeTestRelation')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

This is admin file :
# ----------------- Test form -----------------
from typing import Any
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product, Type, Version, Test, TestVersionRelation, TypeTestRelation

class TypeTestRelationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TypeTestRelation
    extra = 1

class TestVersionRelationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TestVersionRelation
    extra = 1

class TestAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TestAdminForm
    inlines = (TestVersionRelationInline, TypeTestRelationInline,)
    list_display = ('name','file', 'test_result')

admin.site.register(Product)
admin.site.register(Type)
admin.site.register(Version)
admin.site.register(Test, TestAdmin)

Now the problem ? Well at first, there is none. I created a superuser using createsuperuser command. I then log on and create : One product, two versions (of the previously created product) and 4 types.
All is good, and the objects are created, but when i try to add a test...

I get this error :

(With or without selecting some version or types).
To be sure i verified my admin account :


Why do i have this error ? By all means i should have all the rights. I didn't do anything different for Test creation than for the others models. Sure, i used inlines with manyToMany field, but i already did it on another project and it worked fine. What am i doing wrong here ?

Why do you use a custom form?

Well at first this application had a Account part with custom rights. It was working alright until it wasn't. Since it wasn't a real requirement, i just got rid of it (in settings and all other files), erased the DB and migrations, did a makemigrations + migrate... and here we are

I now identified where the problem come from. It come from my FileFields. It seems that when i comment those two, evrything works fine. Why ? Is it a know problem with FileFields ? Is it the way i implement them ?

In the Django doc, the upload_to function state that by default it should use MEDIA_ROOT parameter from the settings as the base folder. I set it up :
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
And i also changed my FielFields to look like this :
file = models.FileField(upload_to="scripts/", null=True, blank=False)
Which should respect the documentation ... and yet i get the same error. And yes, MEDIA_ROOT path exist and it contains a folder named scripts.

Ok i don't have this problem anymore. The problem was not coming from Django or the way i was using it. It was coming from my PC that refused to upload any kind of files.
